# SwiftUI TabView PageStyle with an optional page

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, I want that the state of the first page of a `TabView` determines if the second page is rendered or does not exist at all.

Complete example code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct OptionalPageTabView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = TabViewModel.shared
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            let _ = print("rendering TabView")
            Toggle(isOn: $model.on) {
                Text("Show second page")
            }
            //if model.on {
                Page2View()
            //}
            Text("Hello third page")
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
        .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}

struct Page2View: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = TabViewModel.shared
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("rendering second page, secondPageState:\(model.on)")
        if model.on {
            Text("Hello second page on")
        } else {
            //Text("Hello second page off")
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}

class TabViewModel: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = TabViewModel()
    private init(){}
    @Published var on: Bool = true
}

struct OptionalPageTabView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OptionalPageTabView2()
    }
}
```

**Test 1:**

- start example
- verify console shows something like

> rendering TabView
> rendering second page, secondPageState:true
> 2021-10-02 11:34:06.700231+0200 TabTest2[4708:100634]
> [UICollectionViewRecursion] cv == 0x7fb94c01fa00 Disabling recursion
> trigger logging

- verify that the index has 3 dots
- scroll through 3 pages
- go to the first page again
- turn off the toggle
- verify that the console shows something like

> rendering TabView rendering second page, secondPageState:false

- verify that the index has 2 dots

**expected:** TabView shows 2 pages

**problem:** TabView shows the original 3 pages

**Test 2:**

- start example
- verify console shows something like

> rendering TabView
> rendering second page, secondPageState:true
> 2021-10-02 11:34:06.700231+0200 TabTest2[4708:100634]
> [UICollectionViewRecursion] cv == 0x7fb94c01fa00 Disabling recursion
> trigger logging

- verify that the index has 3 dots
- turn off the toggle
- verify that the console shows something like

> 2021-10-02 11:41:45.968083+0200 TabTest2[4838:106887] invalid mode
> 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on
> _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution. rendering TabView rendering second
> page, secondPageState:false

- scroll
- verify that the second page is empty
- go back to the first page
- turn on the toggle
- scroll

**expected:** Second page shows text

**problem:** Second page is empty

What can I do that the second page is shown or not shown, depending on the state (change) of the first page?
What can I do that the second page updates depending on the state change of the fist page?

(Replacing `TabView` with `List` shows a list where the second list item is shown depending on the state of the first list item)

Xcode 13, iOS Target 14.0

Comment: Try to set id to tab view for force reload ``` .id(model.on) ```

Comment: @RajaKishan that works :-) Didn't think of that because `let _ = print("rendering TabView")` prints to the console with each state change

Comment: @RajaKishan if you post it as an answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force refresh tab view by `.id`

```
TabView {
    .......
    .......
}.id(model.on)
```